# Save struct in middle of running MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, function, struct, save

I have a function that iterates through a bunch of code about 10-20 times, to result in an n*1 struct, with a lot of data in each line of the struct. It takes a while to run through each line of code, and when I do run it, there's a chance that I made a mistake or need some manual correction. I don't want to stop the code from running, because then I would have to lose all the work I had done before. Is it possible to save each iteration of the struct into the workspace, even if the function isn't done running yet, and then overwrite that version with the newer one on the next iteration?

(For example, if I've run the first iteration, I have a 1*1 struct, and that would save, and then the function continues, giving a 2*1 struct. Can I have that override the first version, and then continue to do so, just in case I stop the function in the middle?)

Comment: Include `save fileName myStruct` within the loop? Here `myStruct` represents you struct variable, and `filename` is the file you want to save to. Or better yet, make a copy of old file before overwriting it. on Windows, `! copy filename.mat filename.bak`

Answer (score 0):

You can include `save fileName myStruct` within the loop, where `myStruct` represents you struct variable, and `filename` is the name you want to save to.

In case the program is stopped or crashes while the saving is being done, it's better to make a copy of the old file before overwriting it. You can do that with [`copyfile`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyfile.html).

So, the code would be:

```
%// ...
fname = 'filename'; %// string contianing the file name
fid = fopen([fname '.mat'],'w'); %// create file, even if myStruct doesn't exist yet
fclose(fid); %// close file
for [...] %// your loop
    %// loop operations
    copyfile([fname '.mat'], [fname '.bak'], 'f') %// back up file
    save(fname, 'myStruct') %// overwrite file with updated myStruct 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `try/catch` control structure. This allows you to define what should happen in case of an error or runtime exception.

Assuming your function returns the struct in question,

```
function foo = bar(baz)

try
    % your code here
catch some_exception
    warning(some_exception.msg);% print the exception so you can correct the error later. 
    return % instead of exiting with an error message, return to the caller, the last value of foo is returned 
end
```